# How can i protect html element overlaping?

Tags: html, css

Two Div, overlapping one by another. if i add some padding on `main-wrap-inner` div then it is not overlapping. But padding is not fruitful for all browser.

I have this html :

```
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="main-wrap-inner">
      <nav class="navbar aog-navbar"></nav>
  </div>
  <div id="fullpage" class="container charity-content">
     <section></section>
     <section></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS are :

```
    .main-wrap {
        background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
        clear: both;
        margin: 0;
        min-height: 100%;
        overflow: visible;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    .main-wrap-inner {
        clear: both;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 86px;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main-wrap-inner {
        height: auto;
        min-height: inherit;
      }
  .aog-navbar {
        -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
        -moz-border-left-colors: none;
        -moz-border-right-colors: none;
        -moz-border-top-colors: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color #ddd;
        border-image: none;
        border-style: none none solid;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
        min-height: 100px;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            position: fixed;
    }

.charity-content, .charity-content .container {
    max-width: 1220px;
    width: 100%;
}
.charity-content {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Now problem is the `div` with `fullpage` going under the `div` with `main-wrap-inner`. 
How can i protect this overlapping ?

Comment: can you fiddle this?

Comment: this happens because of the `position:fixed` on the `.navbar`  . see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well this happens because the `.navbar` has `position:fixed` and it stays depending on the document not of it's container, even though you set `position:relative` on `.main-wrap`.

`position:fixed` gets the element out of it's container. so it overlaps everything.

i saw that you set a `min-height:100px;` on `.aog-navbar` so you should set a `margin-top` of minimum `100px` on the `.charity-content` or `#fullpage` div

see snippet below. let me know if it helps

*to read more about `position` see here : **[CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)***

```css
.main-wrap {
        background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
        clear: both;
        margin: 0;
        min-height: 100%;
        overflow: visible;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    .main-wrap-inner {
        clear: both;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 86px;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .main-wrap-inner {
        height: auto;
        min-height: inherit;
      }
  .aog-navbar {
        -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
        -moz-border-left-colors: none;
        -moz-border-right-colors: none;
        -moz-border-top-colors: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-color: -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color #ddd;
        border-image: none;
        border-style: none none solid;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
        min-height: 100px;
        z-index: 99;
    }
    .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            position: fixed;
    }

.charity-content, .charity-content .container {
    max-width: 1220px;
    width: 100%;
}
.charity-content {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-wrap">
  <div class="main-wrap-inner">
      <nav class="navbar aog-navbar">navbar here</nav>
  </div>
  <div id="fullpage" class="container charity-content">
     <section>section1</section>
     <section>section2</section>
  </div>
</div>
```